# Dynamic status message from inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, printing, status

I sometimes do (nested) `for` loops that take a while, so I like putting a message with the index. Normally, I do this:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  cat(paste0(i, " "))
}
```

But I've tried any of these:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  print(i)
}
for (i in 1:1000) {
  cat(paste(i, " ")) # or "\n", doesn't matter
}
for (i in 1:1000) {
  message(i)
}
```

However, this clearly produces text continuously (in this example, the messages would go by very quickly, but as I said, I often do nested `for` loops, which take considerably longer). However, I'd like to do a dynamic message, with a single number on my console which keeps changing (the index). I suppose something like this is possible because when you install a package (or when using `gganimate`), there is that line that keeps changing to `=` signs, indicating progress (that's next-level stuff, but should have the same idea behind it).

I don't know how to do this. My guess is there's something of the same context as `\n`, like `\s` (I know that doesn't exist, but it's just do give an idea), or maybe there is a third function (or something related to `message()`, which I don't fully understand) other than `print()`, `cat()` and `message()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [R - text progress bar in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26919787/903061). The [progress package](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is OK to clear the console each time, you can:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    for(j in 1:1000){
        for(k in 1:1000){
            cat(paste('\014',i, j, k))
        }
    }
}
```